# Java <Optional> Object is null or object's property is null?

Tags: java, option-type

I would like to migrate this legacy Java example code to Java 8.

```
public String getUserSex(Person person) {
    if(person != null) {
        if(person.getSex() != null) {
            return person.getSex();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

How to migrate this to Java 8 using `Optional`?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) and [`Optional.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

```
public Optional<String> getUserSex(Person person)
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(person).flatMap(
        p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getSex())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as follows:

```
public Optional<String> getUserSex(Person person) {
    if(person != null) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(person.getSex());
    }
    return Option.empty();
}
```

In that case the caller of `getUserSex` will always get an typed `Optional` an therefore the caller must not implement null checks.

Instead the caller can ask the Optional if the value is present.

```
 getUserSex(new Person()).isPresent()
```

Comment: You should use Optional.ofNullable() because the getSex method can return null like the given code shows.